# Creating a separate PPTP VPN VLan in network with tagging possible?

Tags: vpn, ipsec, pfsense, pptp

I have a gateway to gateway PPTP VPN that I would like to connect to my network and have it on a VLAN where it is shared to a VLAN tagged wireless router. This way I can have two wireless AP's where one is my internal lan and the other uses the PPTP VPN.

The router that I'm using is a virtualized PFsense under hyper-v which is then VLAN'd to a managed switched to a VLAN tagged switchport which then goes to a cisco wireless AP.

The question is if the yellow part is possible? I tried using IPSec but it does not seem to want to connect to a PPTP VPN.

Here is the topology:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YPYsX.jpg]

Answer (score 0):

There is no ability built-in to use PPTP as a site to site VPN. That's a really bad idea regardless, PPTP's time is long in the past and should not be used at all anymore. Switch to IPsec or OpenVPN and that's possible, and you'll actually have a secure VPN.